# How to manage the Used, Requested and Allocatable in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE, when hovering on the cluster's row in the clusters table, there is a column named: Memory utiliziation (GB). When hovering on it, the following popup appears:

[image]

As you can see, requested is only 1.32 while there have allocation of 8.26. Since the Used is close to the Requested, how can I increase the Requested?
Why does it capped to so low by default?

Comment: Please review [node allocatable resources](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#node_allocatable) and review the calculations of [allocatable memory and cpu resources](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu). I guess it's requested depending on reservations for Kubernetes components, find more information in [Managing Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#local-ephemeral-storage).